# Настройка что Бот печатет AIOGRAM 3 @flags.chat_action("typing") ChatActionMiddleware

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram-3.x

Продолжаю изучение aiogram 3 (делаем TG бота), интересное нашел тут https://habr.com/ru/articles/733732/
Очень хочу научиться делать что бот печатает, когда пользователь чтото нажал и пока готовится ответ ... в целом по посту выше получилось и это работает для обработок пунктов меню (start, help и прочее), если там чтото делается долго (можно sleep поставить), то появляется что бот печатает ... очень круто.
Но никак не могу сделать так, чтобы это же работало с при нажатии на inline кнопки.
В итоге при нажатии на пункт меню (например отчеты) работает отображение что бот печатает ...:

```
обработка нажатия кнопки меню - report
@router.message(Command("report"))
@flags.chat_action("typing")
async def report_handler(msg: Message):
    asyncio.sleep(3)
    mainLogger.info('User press command <report>')
        await msg.answer('Строим отчеты ...')
        ...
```

А вот при добавлении такого же флага для хэндлера нажатия кнопки, статут печатает не работает никак:

```
@router.callback_query(F.data == "btnOrdersToday")
@flags.chat_action("typing")
async def btnOrdersToday_handler(clbck: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    asyncio.sleep(3)
    mainLogger.info('User press <btnOrdersToday> ')
    ...
```

В чем может быть проблема?